# the on click event is working only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click the plusicondiv i want  add the image and textbox and when click the mynasicondiv remove the image and textbox. my problem is next time i click the plusiondiv not add the image and text box.its only happen refreshing the page and click the plusicondiv.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function () {
        
        var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
        
        $('.box').append(textBox);
        
        
        var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg"></img>';

        $('.box').append(img);
        
  
    $(function() {
        $(".mynasicondiv").on("click", function () {
            $(this).parent(".box").remove();
         return
        })
    });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any errors in the console? looks like you're removing .box which is where plus wants to add stuff

Comment: Is there any html in your page?

Comment: there is no syntax error

Comment: can you post the html, at least the relevant parts?

Comment: `console.log($('.box').length);` in the first onlcik function

Comment: You have removed the .box and are trying to use it again when adding an new picture. By that time the .box doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `$(document).on` click for the dynamically generated dom element events

```
 $(document).on('click','.mynasicondiv',function () {
                $(this).parent(".box").empty();
             return
 })
```

**If you remove() `box div` , you can not append img late. Better use `empty()` to clear `.box` container for inner childs**

> All code

```
$(function () {
    $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function () {

        var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';

        $('.box').append(textBox);


        var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg"></img>';

        $('.box').append(img);


    $(function() {
        $(document).on("click",".mynasicondiv",function () {
            $(this).parent(".box").empty();
         return
        })
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: if .box is removed, then you can't append to .box the next time

Comment: @aswathy happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$(function() { ...})` one inside another which is not needed.

Here  `$(".mynasicondiv")` is a dynamically created element. So delegate the event attached to it.

```
$(function() {
  $('.plusicondiv').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    $('.box').append(textBox);
    var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg"></img>';
    $('.box').append(img);
  });

  $("body").on("click", '.mynasicondiv', function() {
    $(this).parent(".box").remove();
    return
  })
});
```

Note: You are removing `.box`, so next time you will not able to append `textBox`as `.box` wont be present in DOM

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the `.box` div completely, that's why you cannot add another input and image. Instead do this:

```js
$('.plusicondiv').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    $('.box').append(textBox);
    var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></img>';
    $('.box').append(img);
});
$("body").on("click", ".mynasicondiv", function(e) {
    $(this).parent(".box").html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="plusicondiv">
    click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a functionality add more new fields on click. I am suggest to use below jQuery plugin. 
[http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/][1]

In your code you can replace instead of

```
$(this).parent(".box").remove();
```

the below code

```
$(this).(".box").html('');
```

because remove() function is remove all the box class html